# Android Studio Electric Eel

Tags: android, android-studio

Since upgrading to android studio electric eel my xml preview is blank it is not rendering. I've try clean/rebuild/sync with Gradle files. Nothing seems to work. This was working with bumblebee android studio. What can I do to get preview working again?